# Get the shared contact list from outlook using exchange service c#

Tags: c#, exchange-server

Is there any way to get the user shared contact list (Contact hared by other user) using c# , exchange service ?

I am able to get the user contact using below code, same way I want the shared contact also

```
        ExchangeService serviceData = Authenticate(username, password);
        FindAllContactsAndContactGroups(serviceData);
        ContactsFolder contactsfolder = ContactsFolder.Bind(serviceData, WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);
        int numItems = 50;// contactsfolder.TotalCount < 50 ? contactsfolder.TotalCount : 50;
        ItemView view = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ContactSchema.DisplayName);
        FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = serviceData.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        List<OutlookContact> ContactList = new List<OutlookContact>();
        foreach (Item item in contactItems)
        {
            OutlookContact Outlookcontact = new OutlookContact();
            if (item is Contact)
            {
                items.Add(item);
                serviceData.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
                Contact contact = item as Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a solution like https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/bbff797d-21df-4bf9-8796-e7b81d818f93/cews-retrieve-all-shared-contacts-available-from-user?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Cheers
Glen